# Flash won't diplay with other computers

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I made a program using Flash Professional 10 and AS3, i published it.
It all compiles and works fine on my coding computer. But when I try to view the program on other computers, via internet, or physically putting the files on the computer, it only displays as 5 dots counting up, over and over.

Comment: Is it a website? Can you put your code up here?

Answer (score 1):

Five dots throbbing sounds like the RSL preloader, and when you run your app elsewhere, it is having trouble locating the assets.  If you are using TLF (or another RSL) in your app, try changing your settings to statically link the library.

Publish Settings -> Flash -> Settings -> Library Path.  The change the default linkage to Merge into code and see what happens.

If this fixes things, then you need make sure everything is available on the other machines and pathed properly.  Watch the load process with Live HTTP Headers in Firefox and look for 404 errors.  This will guide you as to what/how to fix.

Answer (score 0):

What is the Flash Player version on the target machines, and what Flash Player version did you publish the file to target?

If you published from CS4, targeting AS3, it's very likely that the swf requires at minimum Flash Player 10.x.x.x to play.  If your users have 9.x.x.x or lower, and you have no control over their environments, then you yourself will have to publish the file such that it targets the flash player version appropriate to the lowest common denominator among your customers.

This may in fact mean that the project must be written in AS2, if the lowest common denominator has Flash 8 or lower.

EDIT:

There are other possibilities, though.  Perhaps the issue has to do with faulty preloading logic in your swf (eg: you're using a preloader that relies solely on bytesLoaded/bytesTotal vs listening for a COMPLETE event).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using absolute paths instead of relative paths to external assets?

Answer (score 0):

Things to make a note of:

- Running locally or on a webserver?
- Paths for external resources, are they consistent?
- Flash player versions, are they all the same? (if not are they above 10.x)

Answer (score 0):

In the actionscript settings are the Runtime Shared Library Settings. Changing the default linkage from the RSL setting to Merge into Code setting fixed my issue.
The RSL default preloader, for some reason would never finish loading, so my program would never activate.
This method of non-loading used without a pre-loader my not be optimal, but it works now.